# jquery mobile: header on click content region toggles visible/hidden

Tags: jquery-mobile, header, navigation

The jquery mobile topnavigation toggle's on/off ( visible non visible ) when clicking anywhere in the content of the page. How can this be stopped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As seen in the [jQuery Mobile documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/toolbars/bars-fixed-options.html), you can either use the tapToggle option or the data-tap-toggle data attribute.

> Enable or disable the user's ability to toggle toolbar visibility with
>   a tap on the screen (or a click, for mouse users).

Comment: you could add, that as far as I remember on devices not supporting position:fixed, the toggling of the toolbars is needed to re-calculate their position when scrolling. Not sure if the `tapToggle` option was/is available on non-pos-fixed devices.